# Variable that changes depending on the field being used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

**This definitely has been asked/answered before, I just don't really know how to formulate it, so couldnt find anything**

I have two fields `street_1` and `street_2`, the actions for both fields should be exactly the same, so I was wondering if I can somehow use the same functions for both fields, in a way that it would alternate between `1` and `2` depending which field is used.

For example:

```
$('street_1').on('input', function(e){
  document.getElementById('count1').innerHTML = $('street_1').value.length+'/'+ max;
  if ($('street_1').value.length>max) {
    document.getElementById('count1').style.color = "red";
  }
  else document.getElementById('count1').style.color = "black";
});
```

All of the `1's` should be changed to `2` if `street_2` would be the field thats receiving the input.

**HTML**

```
<div class="fieldset">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Address') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
        <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
            <li class="wide">
                <label for="street_1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?></label>
                <div style="position: relative;" class="input-box">
                    <input style="color: transparent; caret-color: black; z-index: 1;" type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getStreet(1)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1" class="street
                        input-text
                        form-control
                        required-entry
                     <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                     <span id="street1span" class="input-text" style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: hidden; width: 98%; position: absolute; top: 0.25px; left: 2px; padding: 1px; z-index: 2; pointer-events: none;" ></span>
                     <span id="count1" class="input-text" style="position: absolute; display: block; right: 5px; top: 2px; z-index: 9;"></span>
                </div>
```

I have this exact same setup again, only with `2's` so `street_1`, `street2span` and `count2`

Comment: Please post your html

Comment: Hmm, why is that relevant?

Comment: We can write a function which takes `count1` or `count2` using functions like `closest`,`children`, etc

Comment: ok, see my edit, let me know what other info is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`street_1` and `street_2` are `ids` for the inputs desired, so you have to use `$` sign in order to do a `jquery` selector.

Also, I suggest you do not mix **javascript** with **jquery**. Use only one.

I used [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) in order to find the `span` element which belongs to desired `input`.
You can do in the following way:

```
$('#street_1,#street_2').on('input', function(e){
   let count=$(this).closest('div').find('span').eq(1);
   count.text($(this).value.length+'/'+ max);     
   if ($(this).value.length>max) {
      count.css('color','red');
   }
   else count.css('color','black');
});
```

Comment: This exactly what I was looking for! Can you explain why I shouldn't be mixing JS and JQ?

Comment: Sure you can use, but usually the code looks more `beautiful` and `structured` if you use only one.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a simple example, lets say you want to do this for two links:

```
<a href="#" id="street_1">One</a>
<a href="#" id="street_2">Two</a>
```

You can easily tell which one is which, and get that number you want, like this:

```
$('#street_1, #street_2').on('click', function(){
  var theNum = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
  // now you can use theNum any way you want
  console.log( theNum );
});
```